# Python, plotting all columns vs the first column (date) in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have csv file which looks like

```
> 01.04.2016;08:39:09;527;61;42;203;20;211
> 02.04.2016;08:43:03;527;51;82;323;80;161
> 03.04.2016;08:43:20;527;61;82;203;20;101
```

I want to plot colomns 3 to 8 vs colomn 1. So in the end, the graph should show 6 lines plotted against date.

I have used the following command to read the csv file

```
PlotList = np.loadtxt('myfile.csv',unpack = True, delimiter =';', converters={ 0 : mdates.strpdate2num('%d.%m.%Y') , 1 : mdates.strpdate2num('%H:%M:%S')} )
```

And I am trying to use `plt.plot_date(PlotList[0],PlotList[1])`but it does not give the desire results.

How can I plot all 6 colomns against date?

Edited: I have posted the code(solution) below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

col_names = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
my_dict = {}

for item in range(0, 6):
    my_dict[col_names[item]] = []

with open("myfile.csv","r") as f:
    spamreader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=";")
    for row in spamreader:
        for col in range(2 , len(row)):
            my_dict[col_names[col-2]].append([row[0],row[col]])
f.close()

for key, data_list in my_dict.items():
    dates_str, values = zip(*data_list)
    dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%d.%m.%Y').date() for d in dates_str]
    plt.plot(dates, values, label=key)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d.%m.%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick answer, use Pandas:

```
data = StringIO.StringIO('''date;time;a;b;c;d;e;f
                            01.04.2016;08:39:09;527;61;42;203;20;211
                            02.04.2016;08:43:03;527;51;82;323;80;161
                            03.04.2016;08:43:20;527;61;82;203;20;101''')
dataframe = pd.read_csv( data, sep=';', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
dataframe.plot()
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(8,3)
plt.gcf().tight_layout()
```

This will produce the following image:
[image]

Comment: I updated the code to actually parse the first column as dates, and not just as strings.

Comment: Thanks, the date format is %d%m%y. how can I change that? Does the program automatically takes filrst line as titels for the legend?